# Error in running the gWidgets2Qt demo

Tags: r, gwidgets

I've got this error while running the demo of the `gWidgets2Qt` package:

```
> demo(gWidgets2Qt)


    demo(gWidgets2Qt)
    ---- ~~~~~~~~~~~

Type  <Return>   to start : 

> ## run examples
> require(gWidgets2)

> options(guiToolkit="Qt")

> ## run examples
> source(system.file("examples", "run_examples.R", package="gWidgets2"))
Error in envRefSetField(x, what, refObjectClass(x), selfEnv, value) : 
  ‘.visible’ is not a field in class “GWindow”
```

please check also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702322/error-in-running-cranvas-examples) I've just asked for session info and a similar error I've got with the `cranvas` package which I think might be related to the above. Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

following the tips from @jverzani I tried a simple code which worked. Then I did some tests:

I get this when detaching the package

```
detach("package:gWidgets2Qt", unload=TRUE)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[2L]], ...) :
  Created a package name, ‘2013-05-23 07:40:37’, when none found
```

Tried to re-load and run the demo but still didn't work
I restarted ubuntu and tried again

```
library(gWidgets2Qt)
demo(gWidgets2Qt)
```

it run correctly, I only get error with the ex-graphics.R example
which fails to run with this error at the first attempt:

```
Error in qsceneDevice(width, height, pointsize, family, the_scene) : 
  unused argument (the_scene)
In addition: Warning message:
In .removePreviousCoerce(class1, class2, where, prevIs) :
  methods currently exist for coercing from “AlternativeSingleEnum” to “character”; they will be replaced.
Error in qinvoke(<environment>, "initScene", ...) : 
  Implementation failed for method 'R::gWidgets2Qt::QtDevice::initScene'
```

and this one at the next attmpts:

```
Error in qsceneDevice(width, height, pointsize, family, the_scene) : 
  unused argument (the_scene)
Error in qinvoke(<environment>, "initScene", ...) : 
  Implementation failed for method 'R::gWidgets2Qt::QtDevice::initScene'
```

But all the other examples work. However, as soon as I load cranvas, with

```
> library(cranvas)

Attaching package: ‘cranvas’

The following object is masked from ‘package:gWidgets2’:

    visible, visible<-
```

`demo(gWidgets2Qt)` fails again and detaching `cranvas`

```
> detach("package:cranvas", unload=TRUE)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[2L]], ...) :
  Created a package name, ‘2013-05-23 08:37:43’, when none found
```

`demo(gWidgets2Qt)` runs again. Has been this incompatibility already seen? Is this depending on `invisible` being masked from `gWidgets2`?

Comment: I'm really curious to know the reason for the downvote...in case he/she is able. the question is asked correctly and gives enough info to be answered I think!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I just installed the whole thing (qtbase, qtutils, gWidgets2, gWidget2Qt) on a linux setup and the demo starts. The ones involving graphs don't really work, but the basic demo does. To see if everything is working, try with something simple:

```
w <- gwindow("something simple")
b <- gbutton("click me", container=w)
addHandlerChanged(b, handler=function(h,...) {
  gmessage("Hello world", parent=w)
})
```

If that doesn't work then there are installation issues

Comment: Yep it worked. I've got something maybe, please check the edit. ps: many thanks for your time!

Comment: The order of loading is important. Load cranvas, then gWidgets2 otherwise the visible methods are masked. This isn't such an issue in user-written code, as you should be able to reference the appropriate method through gWidgets2::visible.

Comment: right! I'll try this evening at home... just windows in here :-)

Comment: Thanks very much! no more issues related to `visible`.